# MongoDB PHP, sort by price

Tags: php, mongodb

I'm trying to sort real estate properties in Mongo database by price High-> Low and Low->High.
This is how I do my query:

```
<?php
// open connection to MongoDB server
$conn = new Mongo();
$db = $conn->test;
$collection = $db->residential;
$filter = array('LISTSTATUS' => 'Active');
$listings = $collection->find($filter);
// Sort by price High->Low
$listings->sort(array('LISTPRICE' => -1));
// Skip if the offset is set
if($skip != 0)
{
     $listings->skip($skip);
}
// 9 results per page
$listings->limit(9);
?>
```

In the view I just do a while loop like this:

```
foreach($listings as $listing)
{
   print_r($listing);
}
```

The script returns an Mongo Object, but it is not sorted right. It looks like it takes the 'LISTPRICE' as a string:

```
Array
(
    [LISTPRICE] => 999900
)
1           
        Array
(
    [LISTPRICE] => 99900
)
1   
        Array
(
    [LISTPRICE] => 99900
)
1       
        Array
(
    [LISTPRICE] => 99900

)
```

There is a huge gap between $999k and $99k, and I'm a sure, that there are properties within that range. If I sort from Low->High, properties on first page are for $1 milion and $100k. How do I make mongodb to take price as an integer or double instead of a string?

Comment: Based on your example, the sorting appears to be correct (price descending).  If you are seeing unexpected sorting, I would check that the 'listprice' field values in your documents are actually numeric and not strings.

Comment: I just checked that. All the prices are strings, not integers, like the are supposed to be. Is there a way to convert them all to integers?

Comment: OK, I fixed my problem. All I needed was: intval($listing['LISTPRICE']) before inserting it to mongo database. Now the sorting is working just fine. Thanks